# Конструктор фотографий на js

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Собственно получено задание написать вот такой [вот конструктор](http://nebo-skinali.ru/podbor.php). Для этого я взял не замысловатый код

**HTML**

```
    <input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```

**JS**

```
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

И пытаюсь продолжить собирать конструктор, но вот вопрос. Изображение вызывает объект `reader.readAsDataURL(file);` и я ни как не могу понять как мне этот объект передать в следующую ф-цию. Например я добавлю под моим кодом
**HTML**

**JS**

```
function test(){
            document.getElementById("qq").innerHTML = reader.readAsDataURL(file);;
          }
```

И интерпритатор выдаст мне ошибку что объект reader.readAsDataURL не определён. Вот собственно вопрос - а как мне взять загруженное изображение для дальнейшей работы?
PS может кто сталкивался и знает что за плагин используется в конструкторе для наложения изображения согласно точкам.

**UPDATE**
Я изменил

```
      var preview = document.querySelector('img');
```

на

```
var preview = document.getElementById('img');
```

А в img соттветственно добвал тэг id, и теперь смог управлять картинкой благодаря id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного не понял, что вы подразумеваете под словом *конструктор* в своём вопросе. Обычно под этим словом подразумевается то, что создаёт объект или, если точнее, функция, которая вызывается при создании объекта.

Передать `reader` достаточно легко. Можно оформить все это дело с помощью объекта, например, вот так:

```
var imageWorker = (function() {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    // Сделаем эту штуку запускающейся при создании объекта
    (function previewFile() {
        var preview = document.querySelector('img');
        var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];

        reader.onloadend = function () {
            preview.src = reader.result;
        };

        if (file) {
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        } else {
            preview.src = "";
        }
    }());

    function test(){
        document.getElementById('qq').innerHTML = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    return {
        'test': test 
    };
}());
```

В коде мы создали область видимости, в которой будет "глобальная" переменная `reader`, к которой смогут обращаться все, кто хочет, внутри этого объекта. Там же вызывается функция `previewFile()`, которую можно оформить как анонимную (для наглядности её имя я не менял). Она вызывается при создании объекта `imageWorker`, фактически являясь "конструктором". Вызвать же функцию `test()` можно будет так: `imageWorker.test()`.

P.S. Та штука, на указанном Вами сайте, работает на flash, от него по хорошему бы уходить, в наше время браузеры перестали любить flash.

P.P.S. Прошу заметить, что FileReader API [поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#search=filereader) только с IE10 и не совсем полностью

Comment: обновил свой вопрос, действительно, не заметил что пример построен на флэше, не подскажете плагин для фильтров картинки, я взял этот https://github.com/mezzoblue/PaintbrushJS но он отказывается в хроме работать, и ещё вопрос, как в примере наложение картинки - я так понимаю наложение нужно будет делать через canvas?

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов, плагин для фильтра не подскажу, но наложение картинок можно сделать и без canvas. Необходимо просто расположить их одну над другой и сделать у верхней картинки при помощи таблицы стилей, например, `opacity: 0.7`

Comment: не совсем понял при чём тут opacity: 0.7, смотрите, там есть background (картинка к которой я присвоил id и которою загружает юзер) и есть верхняя картинка, которая берется из предоставленных картинок и накладывается поверх background. Но накладывается по 6 точкам, которые поставил пользователь, и соответственно, картинка искажается под эти 6 точек

Comment: @ГошкаТарасов, простите, немного Вас не понял. Как растягивать изображение по шести точкам, я Вам, увы, не подскажу.